# Adding and removing form via js not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a newbie trying to learn JavaScripts. So I'm trying to clone an app called Momentum, and I am facing a problem with adding and removing the form and name of the user.

as it can be seen in the loadName() function, if there is a name, it should activate greetUser() function to remove the "showing" class from the form and add the "showing" to greeting class list. If there isn't a name, it should display a form where the user can enter their name.

However, even if I assign the name or not, neither the form will display nor the name.

I have tried changing the names, css file, and other things that I could think of but did not work as I expected. Below is the code that I am working with. It probably is some stupid mistake that I've made, but I just am not able to find out what the problem is.

greetings.js

```
const form = document.querySelector(".js-form");
const input = form.querySelector("input");
const greeting = document.querySelector(".js-greetings");
const USER_LS = "currentUser";
const SHOWING_CN = "showing";

function saveName(text) {
    localStorage.setItem(USER_LS, text);
}

function handleSubmit() {
    event.preventDefault();
    const currentValue = input.value;
    greetUser(currentValue);
    saveName(currentValue);
}

function askForName() {
    form.classList.add(SHOWING_CN);
    form.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);
}

function greetUser(text) {
    form.classList.remove(SHOWING_CN);
    greeting.classList.add(SHOWING_CN);
    greeting.innerText = `Hello, ${text}`;
}

function loadName() {
    const currentUser = localStorage.getItem(USER_LS);
    if (currentUser === null) {
        askForName();
    } else {
        greetUser(currentUser);
    }
}

function init() {
    loadName();
}
```

index.css

```
.form,
.greetings {
    display: none;
}

.showing {
    display: block;
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Something</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="js-clock">
        <h1>00:00</h1>
    </div>

    <form class="js-form form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="What is your name?" />
    </form>

    <h4 class="js-greetings greetings"></h4>
    <script src="clock.js"></script>
    <script src="greetings.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with firing off your loadName() function. This was being called from init(), but nothing was calling init(). I changed it to call loadName() once the window has loaded. There was also an issue with getting the constant USER_LS from local storage when it hadn't yet been set. I've just referred directly to it since it is defined globally. I've demonstrated the USER_LS being set to a name as well as to null (this is commented out since a constant can only be defined once) to show how the inputs appear for each scenario:

```js
const form = document.querySelector(".js-form");
const input = form.querySelector("input");
const greeting = document.querySelector(".js-greetings");
// const USER_LS = null;
const USER_LS = "Bob";
const SHOWING_CN = "showing";

function saveName(text) {
  localStorage.setItem(USER_LS, text);
}

function handleSubmit() {
  event.preventDefault();
  const currentValue = input.value;
  greetUser(currentValue);
  saveName(currentValue);
}

function askForName() {
  form.classList.add(SHOWING_CN);
  form.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);
}

function greetUser(text) {
  form.classList.remove(SHOWING_CN);
  greeting.classList.add(SHOWING_CN);
  greeting.innerText = `Hello, ${text}`;
}

function loadName() {
  const currentUser = USER_LS;
  if (currentUser === null) {
    askForName();
  } else {
    greetUser(currentUser);
  }
}

window.load = loadName();
```

```css
.form,
.greetings {
  display: none;
}

.showing {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="js-clock">
  <h1>00:00</h1>
</div>

<form class="js-form form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="What is your name?" />
</form>

<h4 class="js-greetings greetings"></h4>
<script src="clock.js"></script>
<script src="greetings.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I knew it was some stupid mistake. Thank you for expanding it more and making it better.